# java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format / Unrecognized keystore format. Please load it with a specified type, when using an old android keystore

Tags: java, android-studio, keytool

I tried to sign an old Android application with Android Studio 4.0.1 (which I successfully signed say, 1 year ago) and it seems the keystore cannot be open anymore.
I checked the credentials carefully but I don't think it comes from that.
I also checked the various answers with "Invalid keystore format" on the Internet but get no luck here.

The android JRE raises this error:

```
$ /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/keytool -list -keystore android.keystore -v
erreur keytool : java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:663)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:823)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:366)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:359)

$ /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_242-release"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b3-6222593, mixed mode)
```

It is quite the same message with the OS one:

```
$ keytool -list -keystore android.keystore -v
keytool error: java.security.KeyStoreException: Unrecognized keystore format. Please load it with a specified type
java.security.KeyStoreException: Unrecognized keystore format. Please load it with a specified type
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:1809)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:1680)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:936)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:417)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:410)

$ java --version
openjdk 14.0.2 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.2+12-46)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.2+12-46, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I think I have already met this issue in the past and had to revert to an older version of the JRE to keep on opening my keystore properly (solution I am currently trying now).

- Is this a question of default algorithm that changed between versions? If yes, how can I check my keystore is still valid and that I use a correct algorithm (since I did not create it unfortunately)?
- Do I need to migrate the keystore somehow?

Comment: The default in j8 was JKS, but updates from about 8u80 up (which yours is) have a feature to _read_ either JKS _or_ PKCS12 -- that's the `DualFormatJKS` in your stacktrace. j9 up defaults _writing_ to PKCS12 but reads _all_ types -- or at least all I've tried. Can you post a hex dump of the first 16 bytes? (E.g. `od -N16 -tx1 file`.) That should be enough to identify the format without exposing any sensitive key info.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Good guess! The first part of the file was empty (all 0). This was indeed a corrupted file via a Dropbox share :| Please make an answer asking to check if the first bytes are not null and I will accept it!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found the solution by **deleting the existing *.jks* file** in the **existing path**.

**Either choose a new path to export or delete**. Before deleting I would recommend taking a backup.

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to mismatch of JDK versions. If Android studio is configured to use embedded JDK, try to use `keytool` that comes within this embedded JDK.

e.g.

```
/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore ...
```

Answer (score -1):

I think I have already met this issue in the past and had to revert to an older version of the JRE to keep on opening my keystore properly (solution I am currently trying now).